# Hook not reading e.target.name(React)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

For some reason the e.target.name is coming out to be null in my handleOnChange function. Can someone give an explanation as to why this is happening?
this is the onChange function below...

```
const [image, setImage] = useState([]);
const uploadImage = (e) => {
    const files = e.target.files;
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", files[0]);
    data.append("upload_preset", "barberuploads");

    fetch("https://api.cloudinary.com/----", {
      method: "POST",
      body: data,
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((response) => {
        // setImage(response.secure_url); // new image URL link to store in database
        setImage({
          ...image,
          [e.target.name]: response.secure_url,
        });
      });
  };
```

and this is my input form below...

```
 <input
          type="file"
          name="file"
          placeholder="Image 1"
          onChange={uploadImage}
        ></input>
```

the error I am receiving is "Unhandled Rejection(Type Error) cannot read property name of null". Also, it is not setting to state in my components. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

React uses Synthetic events that are nullified and returned back to the event pool and react state updates are asynchronous so they aren't immediately processed.
[Event Pooling](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling)

> The `SyntheticEvent` is pooled. This means that the `SyntheticEvent`
> object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the
> event callback has been invoked. This is for performance reasons. As
> such, you cannot access the event in an asynchronous way.

## Solution

Save the values from the event in the callback and use those instead of directly trying to access the event object in the state update.

```
const uploadImage = (e) => {
    const { files, name } = e.target; // <-- capture name here
    
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", files[0]);
    data.append("upload_preset", "barberuploads");

    fetch("https://api.cloudinary.com/----", {
      method: "POST",
      body: data,
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((response) => {
        setImage({
          ...image,
          [name]: response.secure_url, // <-- use saved name value
        });
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that events in React are special not DOM events and for your case I'd either save `e.target.name` in variable or call `e.persist()` in the beginning of the handler.

You can find more info [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)